# useRef or DOM api?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, use-ref

There is a confusion in my head originating from react docs mention about not overusing useRef: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#dont-overuse-refs.

In my current react coding style I am using dom api to manipulate dom than useRef hook, because of the rule I made to only useRef when it is absolutely needed, but I can't make logic why I have to replace useRef with dom api. Or should I useRef in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at exactly what the material you linked to is saying:

> Your first inclination may be to use refs to “make things happen” in your app. If this is the case, take a moment and think more critically about where state should be owned in the component hierarchy. Often, it becomes clear that the proper place to “own” that state is at a higher level in the hierarchy.

It says that you should avoid refs (and therefore direct manipulation of DOM elements) in favour of altering the DOM through **state** and **props**.

If you need direct access to the DOM then you should **absolutely** be using refs. It is questioning the need for direct access to the DOM not the use of refs to get it.